# Devolver de una funcion una matriz dinamica C++

Tags: c++

Tengo una función que realiza unas operaciones de forma dinámica creando en su respuesta un vector y una matriz de tamaño que depende de sus entradas.

El problema y la base de mi consulta es que he podido conseguir devolver el vector que se genera pero no la matriz.

El prototipo de la funcion es de esta forma: k(matriz) y pesos63(vector) es la devolucion y las Q60,120... son entradas

```
void kapeso(double k[][3], double *pesos63, double Q60[3][3], double Q120[3][3], double Q180[3][3], double Q240[3][3], double Q300[3][3])
```

Como se ve el primer termino es una matriz en la que no se especifica el numero de filas pero si sus columnas

Este codigo funciona perfectamente si introducimos el tamaño de la matriz desde el main[image]

Pero en cambio si creo una matriz dinamica y uso el mismo prototipo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podeis ver salta ese error en Visual Studio, error que he buscado pero no le veo ningun sentido, al argumento 1 no se le modifica el tipo.

Comment: No se puede convertir de `double**` (puntero a puntero a `double`) a `double[]` (arreglo de `double` extensión desconocida, que es como un puntero a `double`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponte que una matriz tal que:

```
int matriz[3][3];
```

y rellenas sus posiciones con números del 1 al 9. En memoria quedaría así:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
---------   ---------   ---------
  FILA 0     FILA 1       FILA 2
```

Es decir, los valores de la matriz van a ocupar posiciones consecutivas de la memoria.

Si ahora, en cambio, tenemos esto:

```
int ** matriz = new int*[3];
for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
   matriz[i] = new int[3];
```

Y rellenamos la matriz, el resultado en memoria será más bien:

```
MEMORIA 0x0000 0x0001 0x0002 ... 0x1000 0x1001 0x1002 ... 0x1020 0x1021 0x1022 ...
VALOR   0x1000 0x1020 0x1250 ...   1      2      3    ...   4      5      6    ...
        ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              Punteros              Valores fila 0          Valores fila 1
```

Es decir, aunque algunas características se puedan usar igual en el lenguaje:

```
std::cout << matriz[1][2];
```

A nivel de memoria y de instrucciones máquina no se parecen absolutamente en nada ambas estructuras.

Si no necesitas tirar de memoria dinámica mejor sigue usando las matrices del primer ejemplo... en caso contrario lo más recomendable casi sería crear una clase `Matriz` que encapsulase la complejidad asociada a la gestión de la memoria dinámica. Un posible ejemplo tonto:

```
class Matriz
{
  double* m_datos;
  const int m_filas;
  const int m_columnas;

public:

  class MatrizRef
  {
    friend class Matriz;
    double* m_ptr;

    MatrizRef(double* ptr)
      : m_ptr(ptr)
    { }

  public:

    double& operator[](int index)
    { return m_ptr[index]; }
  };

  Matriz(int filas, int columnas)
    : m_filas(filas), m_columnas(columnas), m_datos(new double[filas*columnas])
  { }

  ~Matriz()
  { delete[] m_datos; }

  MatrizRef operator[](int index)
  { return MatrizRef(m_datos+(index*m_columnas)); }

  int Filas() const
  { return m_filas; }

  int Columnas() const
  { return m_columnas; }
};
```

Y un ejemplo de uso:

```
int main()
{
  Matriz m(3,3);
  for( int i=0; i<m.Filas(); i++ )
    for( int j=0; j<m.Columnas(); j++ )
      m[i][j] = i*3+j+1;

  for( int i=0; i<m.Filas(); i++ )
  {
    for( int j=0; j<m.Columnas(); j++ )
      std::cout << m[i][j] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
  } 
}
```

Que aplicado a tu código resultaría en una función con la siguiente firma:

```
void kapeso(Matriz& k, double *pesos63, Matriz& Q60, Matriz& Q120, Matriz& Q180, Matriz& Q240, Matriz& Q300)
```

Por si acaso alguien opina que el uso de la clase anidada es totalmente ineficiente le invito a comprobar que no es así. El siguiente ejemplo:

```
// Función externa (para evitar optimizaciones en este punto)
extern void Func(int&);

int main()
{
  Matriz m(3,3);
  for( int i=0; i<m.Filas(); i++ )
    for( int j=0; j<m.Columnas(); j++ )
      m[i][j] = i*3+j+1;

  int total = 0;
  for( int i=0; i<m.Filas(); i++ )
  {
    for( int j=0; j<m.Columnas(); j++ )
      Func(m[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Genera el siguiente ensamblado:

```
main:                                   # @main
    push    r14
    push    rbx
    push    rax
    mov     edi, 36
    call    operator new[](unsigned long)
    mov     rbx, rax
    movaps  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0] # xmm0 = [1,2,3,4]
    movups  xmmword ptr [rbx], xmm0
    movaps  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_1] # xmm0 = [5,6,7,8]
    movups  xmmword ptr [rbx + 16], xmm0
    mov     dword ptr [rbx + 32], 9
    mov     rdi, rbx
    call    Func(int&)
    lea     rdi, [rbx + 4]
    call    Func(int&)
    lea     rdi, [rbx + 8]
    call    Func(int&)
    lea     rdi, [rbx + 12]
    call    Func(int&)
    lea     rdi, [rbx + 16]
    call    Func(int&)
    lea     rdi, [rbx + 20]
    call    Func(int&)
    lea     rdi, [rbx + 24]
    call    Func(int&)
    lea     rdi, [rbx + 28]
    call    Func(int&)
    mov     rdi, rbx
    add     rdi, 32
    call    Func(int&)
    mov     rdi, rbx
    call    operator delete[](void*)
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 8
    pop     rbx
    pop     r14
    ret
    mov     r14, rax
    mov     rdi, rbx
    call    operator delete[](void*)
    mov     rdi, r14
    call    _Unwind_Resume
```

Como se puede ver, el compilador es capaz de eliminar la clase anidada y ofrecer acceso directo a la memoria:

```
    mov     rdi, rbx         # Se carga en rdi el valor m_datos[0]
    call    Func(int&)       # Llamada a Func() 
    lea     rdi, [rbx + 4]   # Se carga en rdi m_datos[1] ( 4=sizeof(int) )
    call    Func(int&)
    lea     rdi, [rbx + 8]   # Se carga en rdi m_datos[2]
    call    Func(int&)
    lea     rdi, [rbx + 12]  # Se carga en rdi m_datos[3]
    call    Func(int&)
    # ...
```

El ejemplo lo podéis verificar [aquí](https://godbolt.org/g/7Bl1zR)